# Chamar CreateParams de um componente herdado

Tags: delphi

Tenho um componente herdado de um **TEdit**. Já tenho um override do `CreateParams` e por padrão ele possui os seguintes parâmetros:

```
Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_CLIPCHILDREN or ES_MULTILINE or ES_AUTOHSCROLL;
```

Mas as vezes, gostaria de alterar esses parâmetros, removendo o `ES_MULTILINE`.

Especificamente, no *Enter* do componente, gostaria de adicionar o `ES_MULTILINE`, e no Exit gostaria de removê-lo.

É possível? Se sim, como fazer?

Comment: Não pode usar a propriedade Focused ou MouseInClient do controlo para aí fazer um if?

Comment: Mas como setar esses parâmetros? Essa é minha dúvida. Tem como fazer algum comando como `SetParams`??? Ou como chamar o `CreateParams`??? Sei que é possível chamar o `CreateParams` pelo comando `RecreateWnd`, mas ao fazer isso no *Enter* do controle, o foco não fica no mesmo. - @TiagoRodrigues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Penso que seja este o seu problema
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734419/changing-createparams-dynamically

Não vou por o codigo que já la está no link mas basicamente é usar o RecreateWnd mas com uma flag boolean para controlar o numero de vezes que é chamado.

- Criar uma flag na sua classe
- No evento ENTER, fazer o RecreateWnd se a flag tiver false
- No evento ENTER, colocar a flag a true
- No evento EXIT voltar a por a flag a false

Comment: Eu resolvi o meu problema original sem mexer no CreateParams, mas sua solução pode ser válida para outra pessoa com o mesmo problema. Obrigado.